# Problem with applying "Join as Shapekeys" by script with selecting them by row.prop

Tags: scripting, add-on, selection-tools, shape-keys

I'm new in scripting, and I really hope someone of you guys will help me find an answer for my question.
In the script, I'm trying to apply the "Join as Shapekeys" operator to an object, which demands to have one selected object and one active. But I want to use "row.prop" to indicate active and selected objects. For that, I use this code:

```
    curtain_object2 = bpy.context.scene.get('target2')
    if curtain_object2:
        curtain_object2.select_set(True)
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = curtain_object2

    curtain_object = bpy.context.scene.get('target1')
    if curtain_object:
        curtain_object.select_set(True)
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.selected = curtain_object

    bpy.context.active_objects = bpy.types.Scene.target2
    bpy.context.selected_objects = bpy.types.Scene.target1
```

Which of course works and selects them correctly, but the "Join as Shapekeys" doesn't acknowledge that fact.
What can I do for solving the problem. Is it possible to join the shapes by that selecting method at all?

Thanks!

Comment: you are assigning just one object to select_objects in your last line. try doing it with append to not overwrite your first selected object